# Custom layout for Dialog and EditTextPreference

Tags: android, layout, dialog, styles, edittextpreference

i want to style dialogs in my app to have something like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3BAe.png

And i'd want this style also for edittextpreference in preferencescreen and all dialogs in my app.

I search a long but find no solution. Hope anyone can help! :D

Comment: I'd like to see a true answer to this question.  I'm also trying to create a custom Preference Dialog from an EditTextPreference.  I'm not finding any straight forward answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dialog.java (Android src) a ContextThemeWrapper is used. So you could copy the idea and do something like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new 
ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
```

And then style it like you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

More on creating custom styles here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: And how to apply this also to Dialogs in preference screen ? I thought there was a way to do this with xml.

Comment: Sure, just set the style of the dialog to the AlertDialogCustom. Go read the link I sent about Android themes and styles.

Comment: I'll try soon and give u a feedback (and check the answer)! 

Thank you :D

Comment: Sorry but really i've not understood your reply. I try to be more clear. I want to style "dialog header" (like the image) using xml and styles. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can create anything you want. The link i sent was so you understand how android styles work. A dialog is nothing more than another activity, so you just need to create your own activity based off of the dialog and then you are set.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. But what i want is to style all AlertDialogs in my app with XML layouts, not with code. Is it possible ? For Example, if i want my ActionBar blue i set actionBarTheme and custom background colors. Is what i'm look for ...

Comment: Yes in a way. You want to create the XML layout of the dialog like you would an activity. Then when you create the Dialog use setContentView and get the layout you just made. This should get you started. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/ If you want more control over the theme thats where the styles would come in as well.

Comment: Ok, and this is good when i use AlertDialog builder from code. But if i want same style also for dialogs shown in preferencescreen ?